# href HTML call to page "UP" Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

This question is simple, but confusing to explain. Feel free to edit the question.

I'm making a django site and want to link to my admin site.

Current URL structure is `/livestream/...` everything.

I understand these href, all I need is how the path goes down the directory to link to a page, but I want to link to a page that is at the same 'level' as `livestream`.

I want to link to `/admin/` page. How do I do this?

Current URL for admin:

```html
http://{server numbers}/admin/
```

Current URL for index (where the link is coming from):

```html
http://{same server numbers}/livestream/
```

Comment: Something like:
<a href="/admin/">Admin</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
<a href="../admin/">The Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing two dots before a slash `../` lets you navigate up one directory level.

```
../admin
```